# Binary classification model using BERT encoder stuck at 50% accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a simple model for the Yelp binary classification task.

Load BERT encoder:

```
gs_folder_bert = "gs://cloud-tpu-checkpoints/bert/keras_bert/uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12"
bert_config_file = os.path.join(gs_folder_bert, "bert_config.json")
config_dict = json.loads(tf.io.gfile.GFile(bert_config_file).read())
bert_config = bert.configs.BertConfig.from_dict(config_dict)
_, bert_encoder = bert.bert_models.classifier_model(
    bert_config, num_labels=2)
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(model=bert_encoder)
checkpoint.restore(
    os.path.join(gs_folder_bert, 'bert_model.ckpt')).assert_consumed()
```

Load data:

```
data, info = tfds.load('yelp_polarity_reviews', with_info=True, batch_size=-1, as_supervised=True)
train_x_orig, train_y_orig = tfds.as_numpy(data['train'])
train_x = encode_examples(train_x_orig)
train_y = train_y_orig
```

Use BERT to embed the data:

```
encoder_output = bert_encoder.predict(train_x)
```

Setup the model:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(768,))
x = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
sgd = SGD(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Train:

```
model.fit(encoder_output[0], train_y, batch_size=64, epochs=3)
# encoder_output[0].shape === (10000, 1, 768)
# y_train.shape === (100000,)
```

Training results:

```
Epoch 1/5
157/157 [==============================] - 1s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6921 - accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 2/5
157/157 [==============================] - 1s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6918 - accuracy: 0.5455
Epoch 3/5
157/157 [==============================] - 1s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6915 - accuracy: 0.5412
Epoch 4/5
157/157 [==============================] - 1s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6913 - accuracy: 0.5407
Epoch 5/5
157/157 [==============================] - 1s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6911 - accuracy: 0.5358
```

I tried different learning rates, but the main issue seems that training takes 1 second and the accuracy stays at ~0.5. Am I not setting the inputs/model correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your BERT model is not training. It has to be placed before dense layers and train as part of the model. the input layer has to take not BERT vectors, but the sequence of tokens cropped to max_length and padded. Here is the example code: https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_extraction_with_bert/, see the beginning of `create_model` function.

Alternatively, you can use [`Trainer`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/trainer.html#trainer) from transformers.